# How to call form function in menu callback in drupal7?

Tags: forms, routes, chaos-tool-suite

I have **one menu and two functions** that want to call on **same menu**. What I am doing is, in ***hook_menu*** page callback i am calling a function and in that function i am calling another function.Means, ***calling function inside a function in page callback of menu***.
Now my ***PROBLEM IS***, my secong function is a form.

```
$items['component/%/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit Component item',
    'page callback' => '**component_list_edit**',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'file' => 'popup.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

My Page callback:

```
/**
 * ajax popup edit function : ctools implementation
 */
function component_list_edit() {
ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();
  return _mid_component_make_link('Title').component_type_select_list_form($form, $form_state);
}
```

It is giving "ARRAY" as an output. no form m getting.
I also tried to `return drupal_get_form('component_type_select_list_form');`
This is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

After some sort of study, I got to the answer. we can get form by using drupal_get_form and then in return function, we need to render it also.
for example:

```
function component_list_edit() {
  $form = drupal_get_form('component_type_select_list_form');  
  // Load the modal library and add the modal javascript.
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();
  return '<div class="title_display">Title:'._mid_component_make_link('Title').drupal_render($form).'</div>';
}
```